# Flutter app won't execute http methods in IOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, http

I want to use my flutter application on IOS device and everything works fine except for http methods, I have added all the required codes in info.plist as you can see all the required codes are there.

[image]

and when I run my codes in Xcode it doesn't show any errors and it shows the entered username and password in it's terminal but it's not actually hitting the the api for http methods.

[image]

Comment: could you please say what have you done in info.plist?

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: so please add some code about how use http. Maybe you are using it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) dependency to launch URLs, if so have you added these entries to your **info.plist** file?

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>https</string>
  <string>http</string>
</array>
```